# Angular, NgRx: FormControl patchValue() fails with "Cannot assign to read only property '_pendingValue'"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, ngrx, angular-reactive-forms

I have `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent`. Both components make up together a search form with some advanced features. I am using `NgRx` to manage app state.

When I trigger state update in `ngOnDestroy()` of `ChildComponent`, to save `childDropdown` value before it gets destroyed, then in `ParentComponent` in state subscription I get following error:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_pendingValue'

Simplified template:

```
<app-parent>
    <form [formGroup]="searchForm">

        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select
                [formControlName]="parentDropdown.controlName"
                [(value)]="parentDropdown.value"
                (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange(parentDropdown.value)"
            >
                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of parentDropdown.data" [value]="item">{{ item.name }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <app-child>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select
                    [formControlName]="childDropdown.controlName"
                    [(value)]="childDropdown.value"
                    (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange(childDropdown.value)"
                >
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of childDropdown.data" [value]="item">{{ item.name }}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </app-child>
    </form>
</app-parent>
```

In `ngOnDestroy` of `ChildComponent` actions is dispatched to save `value` of `childDropdown` to state:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(fromSearchActions.UPDATE_CHILD_DROPDOWN({ value: childDropdown.value }));
}
```

In `ngOnInit` of `ParentComponent` the `value` of `parentDropdown` gets refreshed from state:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store
        .select(getSearchState)
        .subscribe((state: SearchState) => {
            
            this.parentDropdown.value = state.parentDropdown.value;
            this.searchForm
                .get(this.parentDropdown.controlName)
                .patchValue(state.parentDropdown.value); // HERE it fails
        });
}
```

Error started to occur only after dispatching action in `ngOnDestroy` of `ChildComponent`.

For some reason `_pendingValue` of `parentDropdown` `FormControl` becomes readonly.

[image: Descriptor of _pendingValue value property of FormControl]

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause of the above error. I've accidentally saved `FormControl` into NgRx store, which made all properties of `FormControl` read-only.

Fix is, not to save `FormControl` into store, but only a value, which can be then easily restored/reassigned.